# Web scraper in python to get the list of doctors

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to write a web scraper to get the list of doctors in the US. I have found a number of websites with the database containing the list, including AMA but I could not scrape the list into CSV file.

I am trying to use Pandas and Beautiful soup to do the job.
Please point me in the right direction.

```html
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

dataFrames = pd.read_html('link of the website')



for df in dataFrames:
    print(df)
    with io.open('doctorlist.csv', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as database:
        df.to_csv(database, sep='\t',encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: can you share the 'link of the website' ?

Comment: https://apps.ama-assn.org/doctorfinder/home.jsp. This is the website..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend that you share the exact URL, but that wouldn't help you so here I am giving you what you need not what you wanted.

You're just starting with Python, when a kid goes starts with his education he has math, he doesn't start with linear algebra or trigonometry, he starts with the basics. **Learn Python basics!** Again, you're using modules that you don't even understand:

```
import pandas # This one is Python Data Analysis Library
import bs4 # Used for parsing data( through html/xml...)
from urllib import reqests #Used for making requests such as urlopen (open a URL to get the HTML)
```

Giving you what you need: ('Point me to the right direction'):

[Great AUTOMATEBORINGSTUFF, for basics quickly to advanced](http://automatetheboringstuff.com)

[Learn PYTHON](https://www.learnpython.org/) - [Learn the Basics, Data Science Tutorials, Advanced Tutorials]

*Just a simple Google/YouTube search can give you a really good idea!*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. But, I do know python to intermediate level. I studied python for a semester this year. And, I kind of solved the issue. Turns out the real problem was the URL of the database.

Comment: That's awesome but you know just play with those modules, you might not have used these exact modules.
Anyway, have fun, try to post specific questions so people can answer, you can also edit the question if you want to ask another one and people will answer.